# Post-apocalyptic sci-fi book about a family that goes into cryogenic chambers in a cave to wake up hundreds of years later

Tags: story-identification, novel, books

I am trying to find a book I enjoyed reading as a teen. I can't remember the name or authors unfortunately. It was part of a short book series.

It was a post-apocalyptic story about a family that goes into cryogenic chambers in a cave to wake up hundreds of years later. They woke the children decades before the parents so that they would not have to take care of children in the uncertain future. The father had twin 45 pistols and a motorcycle and went about rendering his justice on a lawless world.

Comment: Sounds like it might have been used as inspiration for Fallout 4

Comment: So the children woke up alone and had to take care of themselves?

Answer (score 8):

Could this be [The Survivalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Survivalist_(novel_series)) series by [Jerry Ahern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Ahern)?

The hero of the series, John Thomes Rourke, is a former CIA Agent trying to find and survive with his family after a Nuclear war between US and the Soviet Union. "He is always armed with a pair of Detonics Combat Master .45 pistols in Alessi shoulder holsters" and his favorite mode of transport was a Harley Davidson motorbike.

After a few books the family go in to suspended animation to wait out the worst effects of the Nuclear War and for a US Space shuttle in a long orbit to return.

> Having planned a five hundred year cryogenic sleep to await the returning Eden Project shuttles, Rourke awakens Annie and Michael early, raising them until their late teens. He then returns himself to cryogenic suspension so they'll be adults by the time that he and the others awaken.

Comment: I've edited to remove the code markdown and just use quotation marks instead.

Comment: Nice find! How did you know of it? Did you read it before?

Comment: That's the one! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks Lethal Carrot - while I think I'm improving the format of my answers, always ready to received help (though I noticed I made a couple of spelling and grammar errors in my answer, which I have just corrected.

Comment: Fuzzybooots: I remember reading a few of the books in the series a LONG time ago - probably in the mid 1990s. Matt's description brought back a vague memory of the title and then google did the rest.

Comment: Matt - you're welcome. Always glad to help.